all comments on my answer were deleted. Why?
I have a question regarding my answer here:
How to merge only the necessary vertexes?
I wrote some comments, no offense at all. All moderators should be able to read the comments.
All comments were deleted.
May i ask why?
Is that there any new policy i don't know?
May i ask what i made/wrote wrong and why all (!) comments were deleted?
Unfortunately only moderators can read deleted comments...

The deleted comments were in no way helpful or beneficial to the question or answer. Strictly speaking, the comments section is not for chatting, but should only be used to clarify questions regarding posts. Furthermore, in this specific case, there were some comments that led to misunderstandings and would have only fueled further discussion unnecessarily. By the way, naming users in the way you did on Meta.SE is not welcome. Stay objective and focused, don't take things so seriously. No further comment necessary.

@quellenform i'm curious, so if a comment or a stream of comments related to a certain clarification has also been reflected as update in the question/answer post, can a moderator safely delete them to reduce clutter? Is it also okay to delete thank you comments that are several months or years old or is it preferred to leave them alone?

@HarryMcKenzie Yes, if the question has been supplemented with content from the comments and this creates redundancy, comments can be removed. Strictly speaking, thank you comments also offer no added value in the long term and can/should be removed. "Comments are meant for requesting clarification": https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
